# how to apply different touch animations

Tags: iphone

How to apply different touch animations in one application like(drag,single touch,multiple touch and others). i appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation on `UIGestureRecognizer` and you'll be off to a running start.